# wslite SOAPResponse - Get Certain Part of the Complete XML Response as String

Tags: xml, string, soap, groovy, prefix

I'm currently using the [wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) library to help me with SOAP web services. 
In my [SOAPResponse](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite/blob/master/src/main/groovy/wslite/soap/SOAPResponse.groovy), I could get something *like* this using its `text` property.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
     <soap:Body>
          <GetPriceResponse xmlns:"http://www.w3schools.com/prices">
              <Price>1.90</Price>
          </GetPriceResponse>
     </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I took this sample from the [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp), by the way.

My problem would be that I would really just want to get the main content as a `String`. In this case, it should be:

```
<GetPriceResponse xmlns:m="http://www.w3schools.com/prices">
     <Price>1.90</m:Price>
</GetPriceResponse>
```

I've tried doing something *like* this:

```
SOAPClient client = new SOAPClient(service)
def response = client.send(SOAPAction: action) {
     Method(xmlns: namespace)
}
println XmlUtil.serialize(response.body.'*' as GPathResult)
```

But somehow, I managed to get something *like*:

```
<tag0:GetPriceResponse xmlns:m="http://www.w3schools.com/prices">
     <tag0:Price>1.90</tag0:Price>
</tag0:GetPriceResponse>
```

It's somehow related to `XmlUtil`'s namespace awareness. But I don't think the `serialize` method provides an overload where I could set it off. Is there another way to do this? I just needed the body content `String`, really. I would be open to the use of other methods. But right now, I'm unsure of what to do. Using `StreamingMarkupBuilder` does the same. I get `tag0` prefixes in every tag.

Comment: What is the problem if you have namespace prefix?

Comment: I'm trying to unmarshall the class (using JAXB). It won't work with my annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used `StreamingMarkUpBuilder` and I had to include `mkp.declareNamespace ('prefix', 'namespace')` in the bind closure. In my case, to prevent whatever it from generating its own namespace prefixes (like `tag0)`, I did this:

```
String xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { 
     mkp.declareNamespace('': 'http://www.w3schools.com/prices') 
     ...
}
```